# Alternative of exists() in UIObject2

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-uiautomator

With `UIObject` we have a method :
`exists()` to check if view exists

I am looking for same alternative with `UIObject2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice; 
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject2;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry; 


private UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
);
List<UiObject2> objs = device.findObjects(...)
// Now you can check if objs.size() > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! *hasObject()* function

Like this:

```
 if (!item.hasObject(By.res("com.mkurbanov.degishmeler:id/item_dugs_date")))
                    break;
 if (!item.hasObject(By.res("com.mkurbanov.degishmeler:id/text_like")))
                    break;
```